# Why "file ./-" works but "file .-" does not

Tags: linux

I was solving[text](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit2.html) for linux,and I found i can find files that starts its name with '-'.
So I solved this problem with 'cat ./-',which gets - as filename.
But what I'm wondering is the reason why using '.-' instead of './-; doesn't work.
Since i'm not just a beginner to linux,this question might be dumb,but i really gotta know why.

i thought .- and ./- is just the same,but only file ./- works and file .- show up error that it can't find the file named '.-'

Comment: It's to do with arguments to programs being prefixed with `'-'` and therefore being interpreted as parameters and not literally. You can get around this by terminating your *actual* parameters to the program with `'--'`. e.g. `touch -- -dashstart;ls -- -*`

Answer (score 1):

For cat it's kind of expected behaviour. From cat manual:

*With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.*

I think it looks for STDIN of your shell in path given by dot, but that is my guess. Full understanding would need to go through cat source code.

Hopefully I've at least point to right direction.

Answer (score 1):

`./-` is a relative path to the name `-`, but `.-` is a different name.  Some utilities treat the string `-` specially and use it to refer to one of the standard IO streams, but from the perspective of the filesytem, here's nothing special about `-`.  In the same way that `./a` refers to the same file as `a` and `./.a` names the same file as `.a`, `.-` refers to the same file as `./.-` which is (most likely) different than the file referenced by `-` or `./-`.  Consider:

```
$ touch - # Create a file named '-'
$ touch .- # Create a file named '.-'
$ ls -a
-   ./  .-  ../
$ make_content() { printf 'inode: %s\n' "$(ls -i $1)" > $1; }
$ make_content .-  # write data into '.-'
$ make_content -   # write data into '-'
$ cat ./-   # Display content of -
inode: 57464057 -
$ cat ./.-   # Display content of .-
inode: 57464058 .-
$ cat .-   # Display content of .- again
inode: 57464058 .-
$ echo foo | cat -  # Consume stdin (cat treats - specially)
foo
$ rm .-  # Remove the name .-
$ ls -a
-   ./  ../
$ ln - .-  # Create .-, a reference to the same file as the name -
$ ls -ia - .-   # Show that both .- and - now reference the same file
57464057 -   57464057 .-
$ cat .-   # Show the content of that file
inode: 57464057 -
```

The utility `cat` treats the string `-` specially, and it does not treat it as a filename.  Instead, it interprets the argument `-` as an instruction to consume its input stream.  The standard workaround for this behavior (in reality, the standard workaround is to have a policy in which you do not name files `-`, but that's a different discussion) is to use the longer name `./-` for the file.  `cat` does not treat the string `./-` as an instruction to read stdin, but as a filename.

I have included the inode listing to demonstrate that after the `ln` operation, both the names `.-` and `-` refer to the exact same file.  This is completely irrelevant to your question, but I felt it necessary to clarify why I wrote "most likely" in the explanation.  Remember that the arguments you pass to utilities such as `cat` are just strings.   Names in a directory are not files, they are (mostly) just strings.  In the case above, `touch -` created a file in the filesystem (with inode 57464057; if you try this on your machine you will almost certainly get a different number) and `touch .-` created a different file (with inode 57464058).  The invocation of `rm .-` removed that name `.-` from the current directory, and after that point there is no longer any reference to the file with inode 57464058 (unless some other process running outside of this shell session created a link).  The `ln` operation then creates the name `.-` in the current directory.  This directory entry refers to the file with inode ...057, the same file as the name `-`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way in which paths are interpreted. `.` is a directory, really (this is a bit oversimplified, but good enough for here). Therefore, you need to put a `/` if you want to access a file there. Its the same thing as if you typed `/home/USER-` is would look for a file called `USER-` in `/home` and not find it. Instead, you put `/home/USER/-`. The same goes for using `.` as the directory prefix.

The other answer is not incorrect, just irrelevant given the question. You asked about `.-`, and that is relevant to `-` which would work for any filename NOT beginning with `-`. To be a bit more clear, the issue with `cat -` is that when `cat` sees `-` as the file, it reads STDIN. It may also be interpreted as an argument, I'm not positive on that distinction. That's why you have to use something with the `.` directory prefix (here we see that `.` is technically a hard filesystem link to the current directory. Try `ls -a` or `file .` and you will see so. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63088) has more information).

Once you put `.`, the `cat` knows that you are specifying a path since there is nothing special about `.` to the OS or `cat` like with `-`. Then, you need the slash (first part says why).